# How to install r packages from Jupyter notebook / Jupyter lab, for beginners?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, install.packages

I am trying install the R package 'deSolve' in a Jupyter notebook, but I get the following error:

```
> install.packages("deSolve")
Warning message in install.packages("deSolve"):
“installation of package ‘deSolve’ had non-zero exit status”Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I get the exact same error message when I try to install any package (I've tried tidyverse, lubridate, and RCurl). I am totally new to Jupyter notebooks but have used R before. Is there a different way to install packages using a notebook?

- I am using Jupyter Labs through Anaconda "out of the box."
- I created an R environment and launch Jupyter Labs with that environment activated.
- I am using R version 3.6.1

Appreciate any help you can give on this. And please let me know what additional information you need to help diagnose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found out you can do it through Anaconda Navigator by selecting the environment you are using and then selecting packages to install.

Answer (score -1):

In notebook

```
load_ext rpy2.ipython

import rpy2.robjects.packages as repackages

utils = repackages.importr(‘utils’)

utils.chooseCRANmirrow(ind=1) #select mirrow

packnames = (‘deSolve’)
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

utils.install_packages(StrVector(packages))
```